# Forcing dovecot to use TLS doesn't work

Tags: dovecot, tls

I look for a way to enforce a lamba user to connect to dovecot server with TLS.

I followed the documentation http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration , and I edit the dovecot configuration as follow :

```
ssl = required
disabled_plain_text = yes
```

Then I reload and restart dovecot.

Then I connect to the dovecot server by typing telnet localhost 143.

But I can connect to a mailbox user again (by typing a login toto password) whereas dovecot should inform me to use tls before.

An idea ? Thanks in advance, cordially.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
```

instead of

```
disabled_plain_text = yes
```

If you really want to make sure nobody will try to login in plaintext, use implicit SSL only ie port 993 and don't listen on port 143.